# Why am I getting an error stating unsupported file when I've specified I want to use .mp3

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to make a music player with Django and Postgresql, I've created a song model that is working in the database except when I try to upload an audio file with a .mp3 extension. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField
    from recordroomapp.helper import get_audio_length
    from .validators import validate_is_audio


    class Artist(models.Model):
        artist = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
        created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.artist
```

```
class Song(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
        song = models.FileField(
            upload_to='media/', validators=[validate_is_audio], null=True)
        song_length = models.DecimalField(
             blank=True, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)
        songinfo = models.ForeignKey(
            "Artist", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='song_post', null=True)
        updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
      # featured_image = CloudinaryField('image', default='placeholder')
        created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='song_likes', blank=True)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ['-created_on']

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title

        # def __init__(self):
        #     return self.song_length

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not self.song_length:
                 audio_length = get_audio_length(self.song)
                self.song_length = f'{audio_length:.2f}'

            return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        def number_of_likes(self):
            return self.likes.count()
```

```
class Comment(models.Model):
        post = models.ForeignKey(
            Song, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        email = models.EmailField()
        body = models.TextField()
        created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ['created_on']

        def __str__(self):
             return f"Comment {self.body} by {self.name}"
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, HttpResponse
    from django.views import generic, View
    from .models import Song


    class SongList(generic.ListView):
        model = Song
        queryset = Song.objects.order_by('-created_on')
        template_name = 'index.html'


    class SongDetail(View):

        def get(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
            queryset = Song.objects.all()
            post = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=slug)
            comments = post.comments.filter(approved=True).order_by('-created_on')
            liked = False
            if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
                liked = True

            return render(
                request,
                "song_detail.html",
                {
                    "song": queryset,
                    "post": post,
                    "comments": comments,
                    "liked": liked
                },
            )
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
    from .models import Artist, Song, Comment
    from django_summernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin


    @admin.register(Artist)
    class ArtistAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('artist', 'slug', 'created_on')
        search_fields = ['artist']


    @admin.register(Song)
    class SongAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
        prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
        list_filter = ['created_on']
        summernote_fields = ('content')
        list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'song', 'created_on')
        search_fields = ['title', 'content']
```

validators.py:

```
import os
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    from mutagen.mp3 import MP3


    def validate_is_audio(file):

        try:
            audio = MP3(file)

            if not audio:
                raise TypeError()

            first_file_check = True

        except Exception as e:
            first_file_check = False

        if not first_file_check:
            raise ValidationError('Unsupported file type.')
        valid_file_extensions = ('.mp3')
        ext = os.path.splitext(file.name)[1]
        if ext.lower() not in valid_file_extensions:
            raise ValidationError('Unacceptable file extension.')
```

helper.py:

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3


    def get_audio_length(file):
        audio = MP3(file)
        return audio.info.length
```

I've posted the files above which are leading to the error, which states the file is unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

I can spot an error in line

```
 valid_file_extensions = ('.mp3')
```

It sould be

```
valid_file_extensions = ('.mp3', )
```

or

```
 valid_file_extensions = ['.mp3']
```

when you want to make a tuple  with one variable you should add a comma at the end so:
`(<some_var>)` its equal to `<some_var>` but not to a tuple with this var, but when you add comma its tuple. `(<some_var>, )`

```
>>> type( (123) )
<class 'int'>
>>> type( (123, ) )
<class 'tuple'>
>>>
```

Comment: Tried implementing those two changes and I'm still getting the 'unsupported file type' error.

Comment: here I printed an exception that is catched and causes Validation error, can you run this and send me the output.
Btw you have strange structure in your function
why do you need this extra 2 steps with TypeError and first_file_check, you can skip them just like that:

`
        try:
            audio = MP3(file)
            if not audio:
                raise TypeError()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            raise ValidationError('Unsupported file type.')            
`

Comment: sorry for formatting :( main idea is to print(e) right after `except Exception as e:` line

Comment: Hi Vlad, thanks for replying. I removed the two steps and the following is the output: 

Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 06, 2023 - 18:51:27
Django version 3.2.20, using settings 'recordroom.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[06/Aug/2023 18:51:31] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8127
[06/Aug/2023 18:51:36] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8983
[06/Aug/2023 18:51:42] "GET /admin/recordroomapp/song/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13246

Comment: [06/Aug/2023 18:51:43] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3195

[06/Aug/2023 18:52:20] "POST /admin/recordroomapp/song/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13441
[06/Aug/2023 18:52:21] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3195
/workspaces/record-room/recordroomapp/validators.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 06, 2023 - 18:52:38
Django version 3.2.20, using settings 'recordroom.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Comment: [06/Aug/2023 18:52:49] "POST /admin/recordroomapp/song/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13442
[06/Aug/2023 18:52:51] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3195
/workspaces/record-room/recordroomapp/validators.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 06, 2023 - 18:53:00
Django version 3.2.20, using settings 'recordroom.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
/workspaces/record-room/recordroomapp/validators.py changed, reloading.

Comment: Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 06, 2023 - 18:53:35
Django version 3.2.20, using settings 'recordroom.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[06/Aug/2023 18:53:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8127
[06/Aug/2023 18:53:47] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8983
[06/Aug/2023 18:53:52] "GET /admin/recordroomapp/song/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13246
[06/Aug/2023 18:53:54] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3195
hip-hop-rock-beats.mp3

Comment: [06/Aug/2023 18:54:23] "POST /admin/recordroomapp/song/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13441
[06/Aug/2023 18:54:24] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3195

Comment: those are not output, its server requests logs, if you're having trouble to find error output you can delete try and except commands for now and shift insides 1 tab left, it will cause exception to actually be raised

Comment: TypeError at /admin/recordroomapp/song/add/
No exception message supplied
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://8000-fintanmi-record-room-cg6j07k7tj.us2.codeanyapp.com/admin/recordroomapp/song/add/
Django Version: 3.2.20
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Location: /workspaces/record-room/recordroomapp/validators.py, line 10, in validate_is_audio
Python Executable: /home/codeany/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.8.12

Comment: Python Path: 
['/workspaces/record-room',
 '/home/codeany/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python38.zip',
 '/home/codeany/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python3.8',
 '/home/codeany/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/codeany/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/home/codeany/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time: Mon, 07 Aug 2023 09:07:24 +0000

Comment: /workspaces/record-room/recordroomapp/validators.py, line 10, in validate_is_audio
        raise TypeError() …
▼ Local vars
Variable Value
audio 
{}
file 
<FieldFile: hip-hop-rock-beats.mp3>

Comment: so an exception is in this MP3 class check, I am unfamiliar with this mutagen lib and I couldnt google examples where files would be checked this way, I can suggest you to try another way to check audio file